# Is there any limit for character count for text in TextBlock of Teams adaptive cards.?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

```
{
   "type": "TextBlock",
   "text": "some text"
}
```

I am using Adaptive cards for Teams, version 1.2.

I was just wondering, Is there any constraint on the length of text we can pass to the text block?

Thanks.

Comment: Not that i know of as long as the card is still max 25kb

Answer (score 0):

We don't have any limit for the length of text we can pass to the text block. If you're using this card in teams the limit for the card size should be less than 24kb. Check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/limits-specifications-teams) for more info.